# Can't find value of some requests .Aspx website

Tags: python, scrapy

In the webpage http://www.wiseco.com/ProductSearch.aspx,
I'm trying to call the dropdown menu selection result, 
and I can't find the value of two headers in the post request:

```
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnSearch.x: 153
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnSearch.y: 9
```

What are these? I can't find these values in the HTML code.

Update:

```
import scrapy

class WisecoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wiseco'
    search_url ='http://www.wiseco.com/ProductSearch.aspx'
    allowed_domains = ["wiseco.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.wiseco.com/ProductSearch.aspx'
    ]


    def parse(self, response):  
        make_url ='http://www.wiseco.com/ProductSearch.aspx'

        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET:' : '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
            '__LASTFOCUS': '',
            '__VIEWSTATE' : response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlModelYear': '2016',
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlBusSegList': '3',
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlMakeList': '1',
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlMakeList': '5866',
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnSearch.x': '114',
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnSearch.y': '6',  

        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url = make_url, formdata=data, callback=self.parse_make)  

    def parse_make(self, response):
        print(response.text)
```

doesn't get data, just a page with an error:

```
                  <tr><td style="padding-top:5px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;" class="bodytext">
  <H4>An Error Has Occurred...</H4>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cursor coordinates on a Search button. From my experience you can use any values you want.

**UPDATE**
You need to send *separate* POST request for each dropdown change: first select Year, send request, parse it and get values for `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlModelYear` etc.

Comment: did and on the last step as I understand  do not click serch button